# Uploader in Chat doesn't use HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, ssl, uploader

In the uploader in Chat, when putting an image on Stack Imgur from the web, it doesn't make the link it puts in the message use HTTPS. [Here is an example of the uploader doing this.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49540303#49540303) This should be changed to make the site more secure.

When editing the message, you can see that the link it makes to the image is not secure:

> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFhdU.png`

Very minor, but, if we had Community changing every single link to Stack Exchange to HTTPS, it seems good to make Chat use HTTPS links with the uploader.

Comment: No repro. The image source and link are `https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFhdU.png` as it should be. (In the example you gave) If you see something else, it's on your end, something is messing with your web pages, check for viruses and malware.

Comment: When I hover my cursor over the image it does say https but the history says just http... so I'm not really sure what to think about this.

Comment: @Catija good point, but it's only a display bug in the [history page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/49540303/history), maybe the actual message in the database is with http:// and it's rendered to https:// once displayed, but it's pretty minor in such case.

Comment: @Catija this also confused me; it seems to be HTTP based on looking at the message source, but when doing “copy link location” (Firefox), it’s HTTPS???

Comment: Yeah, I just copied an image into the Tavern and it's definitely https.

Comment: Well, in the current form this bug report is wrong. You can edit it to report the actual bug which is showing http:// in history and when editing.

Comment: To close voters: this was *fixed*, not *no longer reproducible*. That close reason is for *ephemeral* issues that resolve themselves after a short while, or for questions about features that no longer exist. Questions that are *fixed* should have a [tag:status-completed] tag instead.

Comment: I voted to close my own question @Sonic

Comment: @Stormblessed Still not a valid use of the close reason. You should flag it with a request to add the [tag:status-completed] tag.

Comment: @Megan can you please explain what was fixed?

Comment: @Shadow I’m confused?

Comment: @Stormblessed Megan (new Project Manager at Stack Overflow) marked this bug as completed, but I'm still not sure what the bug was.